# Possible to Connect Netbeans with GitHub?

Tags: netbeans, github

I know the Git integration is Netbeans 7.0 is new and under development, but has anyone had success on pushing/pulling to GitHub?

When I click Git->Push the remote repository url shows up correctly under Step 1. Configured Repository.

But is just stays stuck on " Connecting to repository". It also pops up a box saying "Specify Git repository location" with the exact same url , clicking OK does nothing.

If instead I choose "Specify Git Repository Location" I eventually get an error, "Cannot connect to the remote repository at git@github.com:username/..."

ps. I am aware of the other similar stack questions but they are confusing, one person mentions that he was able to do this, while others mention is not yet possible to use a remote Git connection.

Comment: Did you try specifying a GitHub repo with an `http` or `https` address instead of a `git@...` one?

Comment: Yes it is very odd, seems like a bug, putting in https (or http) adds a password/user field but it tries to connect using 3 slashes, for example `https:///github.com:username/..`  and nothing I do seems to effect it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup github repository in my NetBeans IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456032/how-to-setup-github-repository-in-my-netbeans-ide)

Answer (score 7):

I have had the same issue.
And now it works fine for me.
I have done this:

1 With CLI ( Terminal for me) Define your remote repo :

cd yourlocalfolder

git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo.git

2 Open Netbeans (7.1 for me)
Go to Team > Git > Remote > Push

3 You should see your remote repo preselected

4 in Private /public key browse to your rsa file
 usr/username/ssh/id_rsa

5 Click on Next

6 Done

Answer (score 4):

`You need check 'Specify Git Repository Location:'`
`'Repository URL:' https://github.com/<your username>/<yourGitFile>.git`
`'User:' <your username>`

Comment: Insteresting , did not know that a username/password box magically pops up, but when trying this I get a "404 authorizations error" from github (I double checked my user info) and the git output window in netbeans shows it as a success.

Answer (score 2):

> But is just stays stuck on " Connecting to repository". It also pops up a box saying "Specify Git repository location" with the exact same url , clicking OK does nothing.

I faced the exact same issue and after I did some research I found that the problem was with the password.

###### GitHub isn’t accepting passwords for Git operations anymore.

So instead of using a password, Github suggests using [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

1. Go to your Github account settings.
2. Go to Developer settings in the sidebar.
3. Go to Personal access tokens.
4. Generate new token.

*Make sure to check **repo** scope checkbox to access your repositories.*

After you get your access token you can copy it and past it in the password field in the "Specify Git repository location" window and try to push your project.