# Using Git to put newly created source into GitHub repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository on GitHub at https://github.com/andrewthommo/ComA

I have newly created source on my local file system that I would like to enter into that repository.  After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8456564/418556) I tried using Git from the command line with:

```
git remote -m MyEmail@gmail.com:andrewthommo/ComA.git
error: unknown switch `m'
```

..and also..

```
git remote add -m MyEmail@gmail.com:andrewthommo/ComA.git
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
```

Obviously, I am very confused.  Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

(I am currently looking through [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/418556) for tips..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put your own e-mail address as the repo address, that's not correct. For github, it's `git@github.com:username/repo.git`

<strike>Also, there's no `-m` switch for remote command, see [man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).</strike> The `-m` switch actually does exist, but only for `add` operation, see the man pages for an explanation on it's usage - it is not needed in this case.

You need to specify a name for the remote. Typically it's called `origin`.

Assuming you have issued `git init` on your local folder, correct command is:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:andrewthommo/ComA.git
```

Comment: That last command returns with no error but does nothing.  I am tempted to mark this answer correct & pursue the 'does nothing' in a different question.  I think your latest edit might cover it (I was suspecting 'wrong directory')..

Comment: What do you get if you now type `git remote` without parameters? It should list all configured remotes. If origin is listed there, you have succeeded, and `git push` would get you going with everything else.

Comment: I was in the parent directory to where I needed to be (just for clearing up old matters).  `git remote` now shows 'new' & next line 'origin'.  The reason I am thinking it failed is twofold. 1) I have a slow connection and the command returns almost immediately. 2) I don't see any change in the listing of the repository at the URL in my question.

Comment: I am marking your answer correct since you have answered my original question and given me a lot to think about.  I'll mull it over and form a new question if needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Adding a remote does not create any network activity - `git push` and `git pull/fetch` are the commands that interact with the remotes that you have configured. Seems you now have two remotes configured, one called _new_ and one called _origin_ - i suggest you remote the _new_: `git remote rm new`. Glad I could help.

Comment: Oh right!  I get now, how I misunderstood what you were saying in an earlier comment (it is entirely clear reading it again, the fault is mine, not the words used). Call me a 'happy dill'.  :)

Comment: @laertis true - I have amended my answer.